# Where should I put my code when using a tabbed activity?

Tags: java, android

I am having a rather annoying problem using tabs in android. I am not sure how they work, problem I am having is knowing where to put the logic of my code. say for example on the first tab I wanted to apply a calendar and the second tab upload a file, for example where would I put this logic, I have 3 `xml` fragments and so far I have been trying to code the logic by the `onCreateView`. If anyone could explain how tabbed activities work I would be eternally grateful I used the default android set up for a tabbed activity and added 3 fragments.

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==1) {

                    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_message, container, false);

                    return rootView;

                }
else if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==2){
                    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_read, container, false);
                    TextView textView= (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView_two);
                    textView.setText("Working");

                    return rootView;
                }
else{
                    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendar, container, false);
                 // would I put my logic here?

                    return rootView;
                }
            }
        }
```

**Update 2**
So now I am trying to listen for button  presses and show a toast on one of the fragments,the button does not respond and the Toasts do not appear.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
final View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendar, container, false);

    //final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    //actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    //actionBar.setTitle(null);
    //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"AKHBKH",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Button button1=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_test1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.i("","");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"ddfdf",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

**PS** I have tried all these on the Toast
    getActivity()
    getActivity().getApplicationContext()
    getBaseContext()
    getContext()

Comment: not sure where the code above is placed, but i think best approach for this case is to have one activity, and several fragments (one for each Tab) and use `FragmentPagerAdapter` or `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to show the fragments (tabs), it's clear now that the code will be placed in each fragment (each fragment contains it's own code/logic)

Answer (score 0):

Initially create an activity MainActivity.
You must create 3 fragments.Extend your activity from FragmentActivity and also implement ActionBar.TabListener

Refer this tutorial:
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

Answer (score 0):

You can take three fragments and All the logic you want to implement should be in each of the fragment respectively. Take MainActivity to View all the fragments. Here i'll share my piece of code.

MainActivity

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}


private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new Admin(), "ADMIN");
    adapter.addFragment(new Faculty(), "FACULTY");
    adapter.addFragment(new Student(), "STUDENT");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    //Do Here what ever you want do on back press;

}

}
```

I'll share the code of any one of the fragments: Admin

```
    public class Admin extends Fragment {
EditText aid;
EditText apassword;
Button submit1,changepass;

String id = null, pass = null;
String table = null;


public Admin() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_admin, container, false);


    aid=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.admin_id);
    apassword=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.admin_password);
    changepass=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.changePass);
    submit1=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.submit1);

    submit1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            submit1();
        }
    });

    changepass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent in=new Intent(getActivity(),ChangePassword.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;

    }


//For Admin login Authentication
public void submit1() {
    id = aid.getText().toString();
    pass = apassword.getText().toString();
    Log.d("id", id);
    Log.d("pass", pass);
    table="admin";
   // new ExecuteTask().execute(id, pass, table);
}}
```

Comment: Thank you this it has helped, just a few more problems, it seems like my toasts are not displaying and also my buttons are not executing. I have done what you have done by putting the code in my fragment.

Comment: No there is no error, I am trying to listen for a button I have declared on one of the fragments I used the code you provided but the button in not responding. Under onCreateView. I will update my Question showing the code.

Comment: hv you applied the `button_test1` in `fragment_calendar` layout? you can refer to this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/) for more details. this one is also good [link](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-tablayout-example-using-viewpager-fragments/)